# How do I pull information from one file and split the information to four other files?

Tags: c++

I am trying to pull information from a single file, and using one piece of information (in this reference it will be someones major) I want to direct the information to four other files (according to the major). Sorry if this may be obvious to you, but I really suck at this. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double studNum;
    float GPA;
    string nameL;
    string nameF;
    char initM;
    char majorCode;
    ifstream inCisDegree;
    ofstream outAppmajor;
    ofstream outNetmajor;
    ofstream outProgmajor;
    ofstream outWebmajor;

    inCisDegree.open("cisdegree.txt");
    if (inCisDegree.fail())
{
    cout << "Error opening input file.\n";
    exit(1);
}
    outAppmajor.open("appmajors.txt");
    outNetmajor.open("netmajors.txt");
    outProgmajor.open("progmajors.txt");
    outWebmajor.open("webmajors.txt");

    while (inCisDegree >> studNum >> GPA >> nameL >> nameF >> initM >> GPA >> majorCode);

    inCisDegree >> studNum >> nameL >> nameF >> initM >> GPA >> majorCode;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed); 
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
```

This is basically as far as I got. I had a little more, but it was only to show me if it worked or not. It seems the studNum (student number in the file) did manage to work, however, everything else does not seem to work properly. I am also having issues in figuring out how to properly put the information into one of the four files. Thanks for any help. I have been trying for hours to get this to work, but my mind has been pulling blanks.

edit: The information in the input file looks like: 10168822 Thompson Martha W 3.15 A

which translates to: studNum, nameL, nameF, initM, GPA, majorCode

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the line

```
while(inCisDegree >> studNum >> GPA >> nameL >> nameF >> initM >> GPA >> majorCode);
```

because you have a semicolon at the end, this won't be a loop (presuming it's just this way for testing but thought i'd mention it anyway).

However the main problem with this line is that you've specified your text file to be of the format

```
studNum, nameL, nameF, initM, GPA, majorCode
```

where here you are trying to read in

```
studNum, GPA, nameL, nameF, initM, GPA, majorCode
```

apart from reading a value twice, the first read in for GPA is trying to read a `string` into a `float`, and this is probably throwing an exception somewhere inside `<iostream>` (i don't know exactly what the behaviour is but it won't work). this is breaking your read and the rest of the variables won't read in from the file.

this code should do what you're trying to accomplish.

I've changed `studNum` from a `double` to a `long` as you don't seem to have any reason for it to use `double`, and in all likelyhood you could probably use `unsigned int` as an 8 digit number won't overflow `2^32` anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long studNum;
    float GPA;
    string nameL;
    string nameF;
    char initM;
    char majorCode;

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    ifstream inCisDegree;
    ofstream outAppmajor;
    ofstream outNetmajor;
    ofstream outProgmajor;
    ofstream outWebmajor;

    inCisDegree.open("cisdegree.txt");
    if (inCisDegree.fail()) {
        cout << "Error opening input file.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    outAppmajor.open("appmajors.txt");
    outNetmajor.open("netmajors.txt");
    outProgmajor.open("progmajors.txt");
    outWebmajor.open("webmajors.txt");

    while (inCisDegree.good()) {
        string line;
        getline(inCisDegree, line);
        istringstream sLine(line);

        sLine >> studNum >> nameL >> nameF >> initM >> GPA >> majorCode;

        cout << studNum << " " << nameL << " " << nameF << " " << initM << " " << GPA << " " << majorCode << endl;
        // this line is just so we can see what we've read in to the variables
    }
}
```